# Find ALL matches of a regex pattern in Java - even overlapping ones

Tags: java, regex

I have a `String` of the form:

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,...

I am trying to find all substrings in this string that contain exactly 4 digits. For this I have the regex `[0-9],[0-9],[0-9],[0-9]`. Unfortunately when I try to match the regex against my String, I never obtain *all* the substrings, only a part of all the possible substrings. For instance, in the example above I would only get:

> 1,2,3,4
>
> 5,6,7,8

although I expect to get:

> 1,2,3,4
>
> 2,3,4,5
>
> 3,4,5,6
>
> ...

How would I go about finding *all* matches corresponding to my regex?

---

for info, I am using `Pattern` and `Matcher` to find the matches:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile([0-9],[0-9],[0-9],[0-9]);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);
    
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
    
while (matcher.find())
{
  matches.add(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: i don't think that regex is a good way to go for that task. `substring` might be far better to use here

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Could you please elaborate?

Comment: look at my answer for further information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, successive calls to `Matcher.find()` start at the **end** of the previous match.

To find from a specific location pass a start position parameter to `find` of one character past the start of the previous `find`.

In your case probably something like:

```
while (matcher.find(matcher.start()+1))
```

This works fine:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9],[0-9],[0-9],[0-9]");

public void test(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String test = "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
    if(m.find()) {
        do {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        } while(m.find(m.start()+1));
    }
}
```

printing

> 0,1,2,3
>
> 1,2,3,4
>
> ...

Comment: `(\d,){3}\d` is probably much cleaner :-)

Comment: @AniketSahrawat you mean `\\d`, right?

Comment: Obviously, we always escape the `\\` ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a pure regex based solution then you may use this lookahead based regex for overlapping matches:

```
(?=((?:[0-9],){3}[0-9]))
```

Note that your matches are available in captured group #1

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KCrePg/1)

**Code:**

```
    final String regex = "(?=((?:[0-9],){3}[0-9]))";
    final String string = "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/B8DKit)

**output:**

```
0,1,2,3
1,2,3,4
2,3,4,5
3,4,5,6
4,5,6,7
5,6,7,8
6,7,8,9
```

Answer (score 1):

Some sample code without regex (since it seems not useful to me). Also I would assume regex to be slower in this case. Yet it will only work as it is as long as the numbers are only 1 character long.

```
String s = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h";
for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 8; i+=2) {
    System.out.println(s.substring(i, i + 7));
}
```

Ouput for this string:

```
a,b,c,d
b,c,d,e
c,d,e,f
d,e,f,g
```

Answer (score 1):

As @OldCurmudgeon pointed out, `find()` by default start looking from the end of the previous match. To position it right after the first matched element, introduce the first matched region as a capturing group, and use it's end index:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d,)\\d,\\d,\\d");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9");
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
int start = 0;
while (matcher.find(start)) {
    start = matcher.end(1);
    matches.add(matcher.group());
}
System.out.println(matches);
```

results in

```
[1,2,3,4, 2,3,4,5, 3,4,5,6, 4,5,6,7, 5,6,7,8, 6,7,8,9]
```

This approach would also work if your matching region is longer than one digit